# Parsing XML in jQuery with/out parseXML?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsexml

Both are working... so why do i need `parseXML` ?

```
var x='<a>\
<item k="1" p1="aaa" />\
<item k="2" p1="bbb" />\
</a>';


alert($($.parseXML(x)).find("item[k='1']").attr('p1')); //aaa

alert($(x).find("item[k='1']").attr('p1')); //aaa
```

http://jsbin.com/ukahum/2/edit

Comment: Did you look at the docs for $?

Comment: [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) > XML (data returned from an Ajax call) can be passed to the $() function so individual elements of the XML structure can be retrieved using .find() and other DOM traversal methods.

Comment: @ManseUK ok fine thanks. but why do i need parseXML if i have it already without it ...?

Comment: parseXML returns an XMLDocument - $ returns a jquery object - they are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.parseXML` function will use the `DOMParser` or something similar in IE.

So it will return an real xml object so it will contain things like for example the xml version (`$.parseXML(xml).xmlVersion`).

If you've got xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ok>
    <yes>true</yes>
</ok>
```

and use you're second example you'll get this back:

```
[
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?-->
, 
<ok>​…​</ok>​
]
```

So if you try to execute `$(xml).find("ok")` now it wont find anything because ok is the parent tag and if you execute `$(xml).first()` you'll get an comment and I don't think that that will be nice.

but if you're using your first example you'll get a document as parent tag:

```
[#document]
```

so you can get the `ok` tag like this: `$($($.parseXML(xml)).find("ok")` without problems and there won't be a comment as first node.